# Cannot bulk load from file located on Network Drive

Tags: sql-server, qt, odbc

I'm made a QT application that creates a .csv file on a network drive, connects to a MS SQL DB via an ODBC connection, and then executes a BULK INSERT. The problem is that when the program executes the query using a login, it fails with:

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot bulk load because the file "\10.10.10.10\data\myCSV.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 58(The specified server cannot perform the requested operation.).

I need to be able to run this program from a remote computer, and specify a network path for the BULK INSERT statement. There must be some sort of permissioning that's **not** allowing ODBC SQL SERVER login to access network/UNC paths. What is it? What am I missing? I've tried giving the network path permissions to read from everyone and a host of other things.

Here are some test cases I've done and their results:

> If I run the application on the same machine, using "TRUSTED_CONNECTION", everything works as expected regardless of file location.
>
> If I run the application on the same machine, using a login, and a network path, I get the above error. If I use a local path (C:\ for instance), everything works as expected.
>
> If I run the application remotely, I have to use a login, and the program fails with the above error.

Comment: I *assume* that the Login that SQL Server is running under does not have access to the path.

Comment: Well, if I login to SQL Server with "SQL Server Authentication" using the same username and password I do in the ODBC connection, and then I execute the BULK INSERT in a query window, it seems to work as expected. We also gave the network path READ access from everyone, so, theoretically it should allow it, right? Unless I'm missing some Windows/SQL Server nuance.

Comment: What user account you use to connect to the SQL Server doesn't matter. it's the **Service Accounts's** permissions. Explicitly give the AD account the SQL Server Service is running under access to the share.

Comment: We apparently don't have AD setup on the machine, is this a required step to get this to work?

Comment: *"is this a required step to get this to work"* To authenicate to a different host? Completely.

Comment: Okay, good to know. Thank you @Larnu  I'll see what I can convince our Network/DB admin to do.

Answer (score 0):

> Explicitly give the AD account the SQL Server Service is running under access to the share
>
> "is this a required step to get this to work" To authenicate to a different host? Completely.

Thank you to @Larnu for the answer, this solved it